# Parágrafos na vertical usando flexbox

Tags: css3

Como faço para posicionar o texto dois em baixo do texto um?

```css
.container { width : 100%; height: 150px; background-color: red; }
.vertical-align { display : flex; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<div class="container vertical-align">
 <h2 class="txt-header--2">Texto one</h2>
 <p class="txt-indent--2">Texto dois</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca Flex-direction:column na classe vertical-align

Um container display:Flex por padrão coloca os elementos filhos em linha, pois o padrão do flex-direction é row, mas caso vc queira que os filhos fique um abaixo do outro vc tem que setar manualmente o Flex-director para column

Comment: Eu já tinha tentado e sem sucesso pois perde o alinhamento vertical do meio e o do texto do lado esquerdo. Preciso que fique do lado esquerdo e no meio sendo na vertical.

Comment: @JoãoCarlos quando se muda o flex-direction de row para column vc muda o eixo de alinhamento, então além do column vc tem que colocar justify-content: center; e tira o align-itens pra testar

Answer (score 1):

Coloca a propriedade `flex-direction: column` na classe da div que possui a propriedade `display: flex` (no caso, `.vertical-align`) que ela se comportará como coluna, e os elementos ficarão um abaixo do outro:

```css
.container { width : 100%; height: 150px; background-color: red; }
.vertical-align { display : flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<div class="container vertical-align">
 <h2 class="txt-header--2">Texto one</h2>
 <p class="txt-indent--2">Texto dois</p>
</div>
```